# Extending UINavigationBar clickable area

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I created a custom `UINavigationBar` that adds a custom view to the navigation bar that has some functionality that isn't provided by the origin `UINavigationBar`

As part of my UI I'm adding an `UIButton` that is twice the height of the original `UINavigationBar`

This is part of the .swift file definition

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    // this function is called for each init of this class
    func setup(){
        //create a button, twice the height of the original navigation bar
        let btn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        b.setTitle("click me", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.frame = CGRect(0,0,self.frame.width,self.frame.height*2)
        addSubview(btn)
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is that only the higher half part of the button is clickable, and the bottom part isn't (becuase it is not inside the frame of the original navigation bar

My question is - is it possible to extend the interactive area of the navigation bar?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have create a similar app only with objective-c, though this bug does not reproduce there. It seems to only be a swift issue.

Comment: @rcat24 No I haven't, and it sounds very weird if it's only a swift issue. I just modified the design a little bit in my case

Comment: I have translated the same code from my objective c version ... Where it runs as should. Was the problem with the height of the bar?